# Mode parameter in chmod?

Tags: freebsd

I'm trying to figure out what the `mode` parameter of `setfmode()` which is called eventually by `chmod()` is.

When I print it out and do something like `chmod +t test.txt` "33700" gets printed out. When I do `chmod +w test.txt` "33252" gets printed out.

Is there a way to see which specific bits are being set using these numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to the FreeBSD manual page at https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/permissions.html for a full description of the permission bits.  Note that the illustrations of permission bits are in octal format.

Search engines are your friends - I searched for "FreeBSD permission bits" and instantly found the above link as the first returned result.

From chat:

"I'm trying to find out if the user is setting the sticky bit, so in setfmode() I think I'll bitwise AND the mode variable with the sticky bit constant, then check if that equals the sticky bit constant"

The sticky bit is octal `1000` - see [the FreeBSD `chmod` man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=chmod&sektion=1)
To write numbers in octal in C, precede the value with a `0`, so assuming your mode value is in a variable named `mode`, do `(mode & 01000)`. If that value is zero, the sticky bit is not set, if it is non-zero (i.e., `01000`), the sticky bit is set.

Mark: "Ok my check seems to be working - 
`if ((mode & S_ISTXT) == S_ISTXT)`"

Comment: I looked that up, but I can't find out why a 5 digit number is printed. Can you please help me understand?

Comment: how are you printing the permission bits?

Comment: `printf("%i", mode)`

Comment: where and when are you calling `printf()`?  show some context!  e.g., where is `setfmode()`?

Comment: Sorry. I'm printing it out in `setfmode()` in `vfs_syscalls.c`

Comment: Printing out using %o gets 101644

Comment: The conversion sequence `%i` prints a decimal number, `%o` prints octal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145780/discussion-between-fkeinternet-and-markscode).